# java packages prefix with swig

Tags: java, swig

I'm generating code in java using SWIG. One of the generated class belongs to a package (my.block.myint). And one of the generated method looks like this:

```
public static boolean intersect(Box2D box1, Box2D box2) { ... }
```

This method needs a class named Box2D which is in another package (my.core)

I would like that the generated function looks like this instead:

```
public static boolean intersect(my.core.Box2D box1, my.core.Box2D box2) { ... }
```

For the moment I'm using this pragma in my .i file:

```
%typemap(javaimports) Box2D "my.core.Box2D";
```

which copy the Box2D.java file in the package my.block.myint, but this is not a satisfactory method. Thanks for the ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the classes are coming from a `%import` directive for another SWIG module you can use [`%typemap("javapackage")`](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html#java_directors_typemaps), e.g.

```
%typemap("javapackage") Box2D, Box2D *, Box2D & "my.core.Box2D";
```

If the classes are part of the current module and you want to put the current module in a specific package you can do this with [`-package`](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html#module_packages_classes) when you call SWIG, e.g.:

```
swig -c++ -Wall -java -package my.core.Box2D -outdir my/core/Box2D box2d.i
```

Finally, if you want to make the methods on the Java proxy class take a Java type, rather than a type SWIG knows about already you can do:

```
%typemap(jstype) Box2D "my.core.Box2D"
```

but note that you will need to supply an additional typemap to explain to SWIG how to convert from the `my.core.Box2D` type to the type that the JNI interface it generates expects. That could be with a `javain` typemap, or it could be with a `jtype` typemap and a corresponding `jni` typemap too.